# C# Appending Pdf Pages through MemoryStream

Tags: c#, arrays, pdf, memorystream

I'm currently working on some reports and need to append several reports in one PDF.  In order to do so I'm using ReportViewer to get the reports in different byte[].  Once I have all the reports in a List I proceed to join them using the following method

```
byte[] appendBuffers(List<byte[]> arrays)
        {
            List<byte> byteList = new List<byte>();

            for (int i = 0; i < arrays.Count; i++)
            {
              for (int j = 0; j < arrays[i].Length; j++)
              {
                byteList.Add(arrays[i][j]);
              }
            }

        return byteList.ToArray();
       }
```

Now... once I'm done the resulting byte[] has all the data however when I display the reports on my website I only get the last report to appear on the screen.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't merge PDFs by just merging the file bytes.  PDFs have an internal format.  Use a PDF library such as Foxit or PDFSAM to merge PDF pages into a single file.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [Aspose.Pdf for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx) to [Concatenate, Insert or Append PDF documents](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/working-with-pages-1.html) either from MemoryStream or files.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 1):

As @AresAvatar said, you need to use a PDF library for your task.

Here is a sample for how to do this using [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/).

```
byte[] appendBuffers(List<byte[]> arrays)
{
    using (PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrays.Count; i++)
            document.Append(arrays[i]);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            document.Save(ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I work for Bit Miracle (vendor of the library).